# An object drops 100 m. How long does it take it to fall 100m

Tags: python, math, physics

I need to solve this problem with a python code based on the assumption of gravity affected with air resistance 
y" = g - (1/70)*(y')^2, g= 9.8, y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0

I have solved  question similar using Euler-Heun method for
y"= y - (1/10)*y', y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 1, [0, infinity]

How do i modify what I have to solve the first problem of falling with air resistance? Any suggestions?

```
h= 0.0001
y = 0.0
t = 0.0
v = 1.0

while y >= 0:
    ym = v*h+y
    vm = v - h*(y +v*0.1)
    y = y + 0.5*h*(v+vm)
    v = v - 0.5*h*(y + ym + 0.1*(v + vm))
    t += h

    error = abs(1.0 - y/ym)
    if error > 1.0e-8:
        h*=0.1
    if error < 1.0e-10: 
        h*=1.1

        print y, v, t
```

Note: I also tried a simple euler method but the error is not accurate enough

```
delta_t = .000001  #time step size
y = 0.         #initial height
g = 9.8        #gravitational acceleration
t = 0.         #initial time
y_prime = 0.   #initial velocity
y_2_prime = g  #initial acceleration

while y < 100:
    y = y_prime * delta_t + y
    y_prime = y_2_prime * delta_t + y_prime 
    y_2_prime = g - 0.014285714* y_prime**2
    t = t + delta_t 
print t
```

Comment: Hey, are you using Python 2?  If so, "(1/70)" is 0, so you won't have any drag at all..

Comment: yes you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Runge-Kutta method, which is basically an Euler method of higher order.  You can check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) for more details about that.  It's really common so you shouldn't have any trouble Googling it and finding some good examples on how to implement it.

There are other methods too, but most people (at least those beginning ODE integration) like Runge-Kutta.